# Run Automated test cases with Mstest.exe

Tags: mstest

I am trying to run my automated test cases which are developed for WPF UI testing. When I run test case from Visual Studio, it works and when I run it thru Mstest.exe, it does not work.

I am using following command line

Mstest.exe /testcontainer:dllname /test:AddData

Any help would be great help. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What is the outcome that you expect and what actually happens?

Comment: I got it by adding DeploymentItem attribute on test method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the config file

```
"%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\MSTest.exe" /runconfig:Local.testsettings /testcontainer:Tests\bin\Release\MyDll.dll
```